# Snippets within JSX tags in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

How do I enable snippet completion within JSX tags to add tag attributes:

```
<View style={styles.styleName}>
```

I am trying to make this snippet work but it only seems to work outside the tags:

```
  "style": {
    "scope": "javascript,typescript,jsx,html", 
    "prefix": "rs",
    "body": ["style={ styles.${1} }"],
    "description": "RN style"
  },
```

Comment: Did you try "javascriptreact" in the scope?

Comment: "javascriptreact " doesn't seem to make a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Untested) If you're not opposed to using keyboard shortcuts to insert snippets - [assign keybindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_assign-keybindings-to-snippets) may work.

Answer (score 2):

VSCode added in "javascriptreact" for jsx files. (no need to install anything from the market place)

for example, if you want to write a fetch shortcut

```
{
"fetch": {
        "scope": "javascriptreact,javascript",
        "prefix": "fetch",
        "body": [
            "fetch('$1', {",
            "\tmethod: '$2',",
            "\tcredentials: 'same-origin',",
            "\theaders: new Headers({",
            "\t\t'X-CSRF-Token': this.state.form_token,"
            "\t\t'Content-Type': 'application/json',",
            "\t\t'Accept': 'application/json'",
            "\t}),",
            "\tbody: JSON.stringify(body)",
            "\t}).then(res => res.json()).then(",
            "\t(result) => {$3},",
            "\t(error) => {$4}",
            ");"
        ]
    }
}
```

After adding this to your code-snippets file the short cut is ready for use.

[image: fetch example]

Addressing the original question.  Snippets work in in a jsx tag

[image]

Comment: OP said in the comments that using `javascriptreact` in the scope made no difference.  Does this work within a jsx tag - the original question?

Comment: Yeah, I just tried his original example but added `javascriptreact` as I originally suggested - works fine.  Not sure what he did there.